# Adobe Animate HTML5 not showing all layers

Tags: html5-canvas, adobe-animate

I'm trying to load Adobe Animate HTML5 into my website. Everything looks fine when tested in Animate, but when I add to website the animation plays but not all of the layers/images are showing. I have attached a link to JS Fiddle. The image texture is being shared from Google Drive. Why would only one image show from the texture file?

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/lhovden/ofk9znjv/1/#&togetherjs=LxFd71uC4B`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my question. When I published as image assets vs textures everything worked.